# Designing a Packet-Family

Tags: java, design-patterns, class-design, cisco

In Cisco's UCCX CTI Protocol there are Requests, Confirmations & Events.
(Link for further information to this protocol - cisco account neeeded - [Link](http://developer.cisco.com/web/uccxcti))
All of them basically exist of some fixed fields and some floating (optional) fields.

What would you suggest to represent those packets in java classes?

- Fixed Getter & Setter for each Field on the specific package
- Collection of fixed fields, Collection of floating fields, Generic setters via string name
- Other Ideas?

Maybe someone knows a open source project as reference for designing such packet families?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider putting them in two Maps (one for the required fields and one for the optional ones).

You can increase the safety, if the Map keys are not strings, but enums (using EnumMap)